# Powershell TCP client with error handling

Tags: powershell, tcp, client, telnet

I need help with a Powershell TCP client that can monitor when the server closes the connection.  The starting point for this code is from [here](https://brianreiter.org/2011/06/08/cool-powershell-script-replicates-telnet/) and looks like this:

```
## Connect-Computer.ps1 
## Interact with a service on a remote TCP port 
param( 
    [string] $remoteHost = "localhost", 
    [int] $port = 23
     ) 

try
{
    ## Open the socket, and connect to the computer on the specified port 
    write-host "Connecting to $remoteHost on port $port"
    $socket = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($remoteHost, $port) 
    if($socket -eq $null) { return; } 

    $stream = $socket.GetStream() 
    $writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream) 

    $buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024 
    $encoding = new-object System.Text.AsciiEncoding 

    while($true) 
    { 
       ## Allow data to buffer for a bit 
       start-sleep -m 500 

       ## Read all the data available from the stream, writing it to the 
       ## screen when done. 
       while($stream.DataAvailable)  
       {  
          $read = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, 1024)    
          write-host -n ($encoding.GetString($buffer, 0, $read))  
       } 

       ## Read the user's command, quitting if they hit ^D 
       $command = read-host

       ## Write their command to the remote host      
       $writer.WriteLine($command) 
       $writer.Flush() 
    } 
}
finally
{
    ## Close the streams 
    $writer.Close() 
    $stream.Close()
}
```

The problem is when the server closes the port the client continues to wait.  How can I use a buffered read but still check if the port is still open?  I dont need to know immediately if the port closes, just after a few minutes.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [Socket Poll](https://learn-powershell.net/2015/03/29/checking-for-disconnected-connections-with-tcplistener-using-powershell/)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The method of polling looks like what I need.  To get my script working I ended up doing the following:
#check if socket is still open
       $now = Get-Date
       if($now.TimeOfDay -ge $timer.TimeofDay) {
            $socket = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($remoteHost, $port) 
            if($socket -eq $null) { return; }
            $stream = $socket.GetStream()  
            $timer = $now + "00:05:00"  
        }
I will switch to the method you provided.